# Compare two dataframes and make a summary dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames that I want to make a comparison between these two bases on
['Quantity','Unit price','Total price'] columns, and at the end, merge both data frames into one data frame contains with evaluation for each column that if they are equal so should be '0' otherwise '1'.like image Final. If someone could guide me.  Thanks :)

Ground truth:

[image: Ground Truth]

Extraction:

[image: Extraction]

Final:

[image: Final]

```
df = df_GT.merge(df_Ex.round(),how ='outer',on =['Quantity','Unit price','Total price'],
                suffixes=('_GT', '_Extraction'),indicator ='same')
```

This is what I did but I just got stuck in the no similarity between values and their validation.